# Get current page params '$this->params' in cake php when an ajax request is passed from it

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Get current page params `$this->params` in cake php when an ajax request is passed from it

Is it possible to get base page params  directly to ajax request function in cake php

For example

`http://localhost/pages/view/2`  is my  base path.

I am requesting a ajax  `/pages/customFunction` from base page.

Is it possible to get base page params as 'pages' , 'view' and 2 inside  `function customFunction()` without passing through ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not except you're using the session to store the information there.

You're making two https requests, one for the add and another one to customFunction. That's how http works.

Simply pass the same params you have used for the add method to the custumFunction in the ajax request. I don't see a problem to get this done.

Comment: The customFunction is pagination function, at first time I will get correct controller, action and params. From the next time onwards the controller will get correctly, but action and params will not be correct one in pagination function as it will change action to ajax function name, if I use ajax ...

Comment: You can change that too see the options property here. http://api20.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper